# Why is ArcPy / ArcGIS hanging when converting batches of large rasters to points?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, raster-to-point

There are 102 raster files in total that I want to convert to points. Each raster file is 2160x4320 pixels. When running the script in the code block below, the process hangs into the third or fourth raster file, regardless of if I take a random sample of the 102 rasters to start with. Even taking a subset of six of these rasters and converting them to points leads my machine to hang on the third raster file.

The first two rasters both take around 10 minutes to convert, and the third raster file was processing for 10 hours before I stopped it. While the third raster file was being processed, I noticed that ArcMap's associated RuntimeLocalServer.exe private memory allocation for RAM grew from ~900mb after completing the first two and starting on the third to ~2600mb once I stopped the process.

Regarding the machine I'm using - I'm using ArcGIS 10.5 on a computer with a i7-6700K processor, 32GB ram, and a terabyte SSD. The computer is good working order in terms of software and hardware.

When run on a desktop a few years older with only 16GB of RAM, the same script below has crashed ArcGIS and left the routine incomplete after about three files are processed. It seems like ArcGIS isn't clearing VRAM or RAM used for already-converted raster files, but I have no idea if this is actually the problem.

Is there some ArcPy memory management command that I can include in my code below? Why is this process consistently failing to finish?

```
# Convert all rasters in a directory to points.

import arcpy
import os

conversionList = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"D:/data/crops/earthstat/HarvestedAreaYieldMajorCrops_Geotiff/"):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".tif"):
            fpath = root + "/"+  f
            conversionList.append(fpath)

outputPath = r"D:/data/crops/earthstat/HarvestedAreaYieldMajorCrops_Points/"

for item in conversionList:
    infile = str(item)
    outfile = outputPath + item.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0] + ".shp"
    arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(infile, outfile, "Value")
```

Comment: Are you running this script from within ArcGIS or using standalone Python?

Comment: I have used the standalone Python script above as well as putting the same script into ArcMap's Python window. Results are the same.

Comment: Try converting to feature classes in a file geodatabase instead of shapefiles

Comment: I have no idea what is happening behind the scenes in terms of memory consumption for this particular GP tool, but a couple of things to try: 1. Shapefile .dbf can only be 2GB in size which may cause troubles when exporting a large raster. So, export to file gdb. 2. Install Background processing for 64bit Python as this will let you exploit those ~14GB RAM available on the 16GB machine.

Comment: Thanks BERA and Alex Tereshenkov. I will try what you suggest and report back.

Comment: Any chance there is something actually wrong with the 3rd tif? I am not a Python expert, and code looks good, but did you print and verify that all conversion paths in list are actually correct? Personally, I would add some "If file exists" check procedure in the first loop.  Also Backround geoprocessing is on or off? If on, try turning it off then run again.

Comment: @Jakub - It wasn't a problem with the integrity of the tiff files. The third or fourth TIFF file was all the script would reach in the list of 102, even if I randomized the order of the list.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov and BERA as well, I installed the 64bit background geoprocessing package and ran the script within the geodatabase. Even using the Python console within ArcMap, all 102 raster files finished quickly, with approximately 1 minute 5 seconds per raster file.

This fixes my problem, but this isn't necessarily a solution. I would hope that someone could explain the enormous difference in processing time. I will uninstall the 64bit background processing package and see if the file geodatabase was the reason for the speed up.